# Android Studio NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager on KitKat

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-4.4-kitkat

Please do not mark this post as duplicate, I am adding this query after checking all the existing answers.

The issue I am facing is **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager** on **Android Studio**.
I am trying to build and run my android code with **build version "28.0.3"**, this works fine with Api version 23 - marshmallow but **throws NoClassDefFound Error when I try to run the same code with Kitkat - api version 19**.

I tried to migrate my app to AndoridX as mentioned in the Android developer site but that didn't worked either. Any help on this issue is appreciated.

[image: AndroidX Migration]

*Original gradle dependencies that is working on Api level 23 but not on 19*

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, eventFilter);

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

`dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"
    implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0'
    implementation ('com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}`

*Migration AndroidX Dependencies:*
`dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"
    implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0'
    implementation ('com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}`

Logs : 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.<init>(LocalBroadcastManager.java:115)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:107)
        at com.example.amit.myApplication.onCreate(myApplication.java:218)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 0):

Old support libraries are no longer being maintained. Use the latest version from AndroidX:

```
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

And import from new package:

```
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
```

Comment: Hi @Chintan, I tried your solution on both after migrating app to Androidx and without migration as well,  but didn't get any luck. App still crashing on API 19 and showing the same error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1` .